# I am getting json data in a different format in codeigniter. Why?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to make and return json data using codeigniter. I want to receive that data in this format

```
[
  {
     'title': 'this is title',
     'desc':  'THis is desc'
  },
   {
     'title': 'this is title',
     'desc':  'THis is desc'
  }
]
```

But I am receiving it this way

```
[[{"title":"this is title","desc":"this is desc"}],[{"title":"this is title","description":"this is desc"}]]
```

how can I change this format to above one?

here is my code

```
public function v1 () {
    $this->load->model('model_jokes');

    $jokes = $this->model_jokes->readJokes();
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($jokes as $joke) {
        $arr[] = array(
                array(
                    'title' => $joke->title,
                    'description' => $joke->joke
                )
            );
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: The answer is given in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152417/only-last-row-is-returned-in-json-using-codeigniter

Comment: No. It was a different question. That question is regarding it only returns last row on the data not whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the assignment inside `foreach` as

```
$arr[] = array(
  'title' => $joke->title,
  'description' => $joke->joke
);
```

Otherwise you will get a multi-dimensional array for each `$joke`.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding array of array element each time in a loop. Instead just add single array.

```
public function v1 () {
    $this->load->model('model_jokes');

    $jokes = $this->model_jokes->readJokes();
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($jokes as $joke) {
        $arr[] = array(
                    'title' => $joke->title,
                    'description' => $joke->joke
            );
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
echo '<pre>'.json_encode($arr).'</pre>';
```